# Can you disable HTTP/1.1 in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, http2

Is that possible? If clients are also configured to use HTTP/2 it'd be also good get rid of the upgrade step from 1.1 to 2.

Answer (score 2):

As of Spring Boot 2.1.0, there's no configuration to disable HTTP/1.1 (and it's probably a bit too early to consider it though).

---

The [documetation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-configure-http2), however, states that you *can enable HTTP/2 support* (as opposite of disabling support for older versions):

> You can enable HTTP/2 support in your Spring Boot application with the `server.http2.enabled` configuration property. This support depends on the chosen web server and the application environment.

As follows:

```batch
# Whether to enable HTTP/2 support, if the current environment supports it
server.http2.enabled=true
```

A list of common application properties is available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).